# Free java hosting?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Anyone know url of free java hosting? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Free JSP and Servlet Hosting Directory](http://www.oinko.net/freejsp/)
- [EATJ](http://www.eatj.com/)
- [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)

I hop it will help you.